# First data not showing when I get data from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show all of the data from my MySQL database to this PHP file. However, when I run the code, all of the data shows up, but the first data from the database is not showing up. I wonder is there any mistake in the code?

```html
<?php
session_start();
include "db.php";

   echo'<table class="table table-bordered" >';
   echo"<tr>";
   echo"<td>No.</td>";
   echo"<td>Nama Masakan</td>";
   echo"<td>Jumlah</td>";
   echo"<td>Keterangan</td>";
   echo"<td></td>";
   echo"<td></td>";
   echo"<td></td>";
   echo"</tr>";

$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$_SESSION["tabel"]."`");
if($row=mysql_fetch_row($query)>0){

   $i=1;
   
   
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
       echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
    echo $i;
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>{$row['nama_masakan']}</td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='jumlah[]' id='jumlah$i' disabled='true' value='{$row['jumlah']}'/> </td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='keterangan[]' id='keterangan$i' disabled='true' value='{$row['keterangan']}'/></td>";
    echo"<td><button type='button' name='edit' id='edit$i' onClick='edit($i)'>Edit</button></td>";
    echo"<td><button type='button' name='save' id='save$i' disabled='true' onClick='save($i)'>Save</button></td>";
    echo"<td><button type='button' name='delete' id='del$i' onClick='del($i)'>Del</button></td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    $i++;
   } 
  
} else{
echo "Tidak ada Pesanan Makanan"; 
}
 echo"</Table>";

?> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory chastisement: [don't use the `mysql` API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1). It's deprecated and lacks numerous crucial features. Now on to my answer...

Each time you call `mysql_fetch_*` it retrieves the *next* row from the result. You call `mysql_fetch_row` once in your `if` (which fetches the first row) then again in your `while` (which fetches the second row) before you do anything with the row you've fetched.

In your `if`, instead of `fetch` you should be checking `mysql_num_rows` to determine whether you have any data:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    $i=1;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
```

Once you have that change working, you would be well-served to read up on the `mysqli` API and begin converting your code.